# Prolog-function that saves output into a list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a function that saves all the output of another function into a list. For example, I have a function that outputs the following...

```
findComb([1,2,3,4],B).

 ?- [1,3];
 ?- [1,3];
 ?- [1,4];
 ?- [1,4];
 ?- false
```

I want a function that saves all the output into a list. For example...

```
?- [[1,3],[1,3],[1,4],[1,4]]
```

This is my attempt at creating such a function but it results in an infinite loop...

```
convert(List,Accum) :-
    findComb(List,M),
    M \= false,
    convert(List,[M|Accum]).
```

I am new to prolog so please try to keep it as simple and understandable as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `findall` predicate.

Comment: I think you're right, but I can't figure out how to use it for my purpose.